# jQuery get/toggle class and animate if

Tags: jquery, if-statement, jquery-animate

Still learing dem jQueries and found another problem - i wanted to recreate a classical feedback panel/slide from the side thing.

HTML

```
<div id="foobar" class="slide closed">
            <img class="slidebutton" src="img/slide.png" alt="slide">

            <div id="slidetext">
                <p>slide me out</p>
            </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".slidebutton").click(function () {
    $('#foobar').toggleClass("open closed");

    if $('#foobar').attr('class') returns 'closed' {
        $( "#foobar" ).animate({ "left": "+=200px" }, "slow" );
    }
    else {
        $( '#foobar' ).animate({ "right": "+=200px" }, "slow" );
    });
});

});
```

if I test the toggle without if statement it works so I assume I made a mistake considering the animation?

Infinite knowledge powers of ze interwebz be welcome :)

Comment: have you tried the `hasClass` method?  `if($('#foo').hasClass('abc')) {...`

Comment: Can you post a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)? I feel that you're overcomplicating this a little, but I'm not quite sure what's going on or what the classes do.

Comment: I dont really think I am overcomplicating, or how would you do an identifier to know if jquery should do the slide-out or slide-in at click? 

here is a jfiddle I derived from the already posted answers:
http://jsfiddle.net/NMX8C/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) to check if it has a class.

```
if($('#foobar').hasClass('closed'))
{
    $( "#foobar" ).animate({ "left": "+=200px" }, "slow" );
}
else
{
    $( '#foobar' ).animate({ "right": "+=200px" }, "slow" );
}
```

Comment: @DavidThomas Indeed I did. Fixed it